# Git Maintaining history Streamlined

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have taken a branch(Branch A) from Master and done some commits on the Branch A, in the meantime, some Commits are merged on Master from Another Branch B 
Problem is: I have to Push my commits and Merge to Master
so which approach will be best :

1)I Push My commits to remote Branch A, then checkout master, then take a pull and then merge the Branch A in master and Push the merged code in Master.

2)I check out master and git pull with rebasing the master and then Checkout Branch A and Push my commits to Branch A and then Checkout Master and merge Branch A in Master and Push the Master.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: read the question carefully, I'm asking about the approach which should  prefer and I Know when to use the git rebase and and git merge

Comment: There is no right answer to this question, both are perfectly valid, equally good, and which is best entirely depends on secondary preferences about workflow and history structure. If you go the merge route, be sure to merge master into branchA before merging branchA into master. that way any conflicts can be resolved and tested before updating your main line of code.

Comment: merge master into BranchA after taking the (git pull --rebase on master)? or before @LightBender

Comment: You always want to integrate code on the feature branch, doing a rebase will integrate your code on top of their code. Merging master into your branch will integrate their code into your code. Either way, you get code on a branch that can be tested *before* you merge it into the master branch. Not doing this step is one of the most common causes of production bugs I've encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need neither, assuming that you are working in a pure git environment (i.e., no "external" workflow management like Github's "pull requests" or something like that).

Simply merge your branch locally, and then push those of the two that you want to have remote (i.e., pushing `branchA` is only necessary if you want to keep that branch long-term, and also want to have it remotely viewable for posteriority).

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master    # just in case someone else changed it meanwhile...
git merge branchA
git push origin master branchA
```

Explanation:

First, you checkout `master`. This means your local "current" branch is `master`, and the working directory represents its current file tree.

Next, you pull the `master` from `origin`. This is useful if someone else, meanwhile, committed something onto the remote master; it means that you're now up to date. If you know that nobody could have done that (because you're the only one working on it), then you can skip this step.

Thirdly, you merge your `branchA` into your local `master`. I assume that you own `branchA`, that is, there is no chance that there could be a more recent `branchA`on `origin`, hence no further push/pull is necessary.

Finally, you push both `master` and `branchA` back to `origin`. The remote (and your local) `master` will now contain the merge commit that includes all changes originating in `branchA`. `branchA` will be unchanged and stick around for either historical purposes, or for further changes.

## On rebase vs. merge

Some people never rebase, but always merge. Other people like to rebase.

You commented that you know about the difference, so I'll not write much. But for this particular usecase (getting changes from a feature branch back into `master`), merging is the correct operation, and there should not be a `rebase` involved.

If you were asking how to get changes from `master` back into `branchA`, *then* we would talk about whether you would use `rebase` or `merge`.

Comment: I want both branches to be remotely available,  can you explain a little bit more about your approach  @AnoE

Comment: Directly merging is not necessarily the correct option. You are correct a merge is necessary at some point, but it sounds like the questioner is looking at a direct three-way merge vs a rebase then fast-forward merge. Both will get you to the same merged codebase, only in different ways. Which is correct depends on the workflow of the project, the preferences of the team, etc.

Comment: @LightBender, OP specifically states `I have to Push my commits [in branchA] and Merge to Master`.

Comment: Agreed, but in the context of "maintaining [a] streamlined history" what you do with the commits on branchA before that merge is a consideration that needs to be addressed as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for giving me a brief explanation for my query,
@LightBender

Comment: Also, @AnoE for a brief explanation and giving time to this question

Answer (score 1):

Push `branchA` to remote:

```
$ git push origin branchA
```

Checkout to `master`, update `master` with `remote master`. Pull `branchA` into `master`, then push to remote:

```
$ git checkout master      # master branch
$ git pull origin master   # update local master history = remote master history

$ git pull origin branchA  # pull 'branchA' changes into 'master' branch  
$ git push origin master   # update remote master with branchA changes
```